# TFS: Rolling back a Changeset but checking out first?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to rollback a changeset but have it checked out first.

I have rolled it back because i wasn't ready but i didn't want it deleted completly, i wanted it checkouted so i can change it..

Hence the server (TFS) would have the files rollbacked which is great but i would have those files checked out so i can amend my issues and re checkin

is this possible?

I have the CmdLets installed too so using the command is no problem either.

The problem is I am rolling back because it was wrong but i want all those files checkout in my solution so i can amend them before doing a new checkin

THanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you want to do.  We are going to start by fully rolling back the changeset that you want out of the server.

Let's call the changeset you want to rollback changeset 10.  Rollback changeset 10 and check-in the result.  Let's say that created changeset 20.

Now, to get your files back to the state where you can edit them, you want to rollback changeset *20*.  This will have the effect of putting your workspace in a state where your original changes are pended and you can modify them before you check in.

Comment: This is excellent! However, the pending change on each file is "edit, rollback", is there any way to remove the "rollback" change type and check this in regularly as only "edit"?

Comment: Not without saving off the content, undoing the change and then repending it just as an edit.  That said, why do you want to remove the rollback change type? You are, in fact, rolling back a changeset, why don't you want that recorded?

Comment: Because it's going to take time until I can check-in my fix for the original check-in, and there will be several check-ins until that, including to the files I'm going to check-in, so there will be merges too. Bottom line, I don't trust a rollback so far into the past, so I'll do as you suggested.